# Should you overload the "=" operator by reference or with a temporary variable?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference, memcpy, temporary-objects

Consider a class with just a single member for this example.

```
class tester
{
public:
    int tester_value;

    tester(){}

    tester(int test_val)
    {
      tester_value = test_val;
    } 
    

    tester(const tester & data) : tester_value(data.tester_value)
    {
      std::cout << "Copied!" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I was curious as to the proper way to overload the `=` operator and why one way works and another does not.

For example, this operator overload does not seem to properly copy the data from one object to another.

**Example 1**:

```
tester operator=(const tester & data) const
{
  tester temp;    
  std::memcpy(&temp, &data, sizeof(tester));
  return temp;
}
```

However, this example works just fine.

**Example 2:**

```
tester& operator=(const tester & data)
{        
  tester_value = data.tester_value;

  return *this;
}
```

When using the following code to test each example...

```
  tester my_test = tester(15);
  
  tester my_second_test = tester(20);    
  
  my_test = my_second_test;
  
  std::cout << "my_test.tester_value:" << my_test.tester_value << std::endl;
  
  std::cout << "my_second_test.tester_value:" << my_second_test.tester_value << std::endl;
```

The result for example 1 will be:

```
15
20
```

While the result for example 2 will be:

```
20
20
```

So,

**Question 1:** Why is it that using a temporary variable and `memcpy()` does not work properly to copy the data from one object to another when overloading the `=` operator?

**Question 2:** What is the proper and most efficient way to do overload this operator?

I appreciate any explanation, I am still getting used to the C++ language.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With a simple class like this one `memcpy` shouldn't be harmful, but it's vast overkill and with a more complicated class it would be fatal. In C++ you should keep `memcpy` in the toolbox until you have a very good reason to take it out an use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: It's very weird for `operator=` to be `const`. The whole point is that you're changing the left hand side of the `=` by assigning something to it.

Comment: Your example 1 is flawed.   Don't use `std::memcpy()` on instances of non-trivial classes (common cases of this include a class with any virtual functions or one with a hand-rolled assignment operator. constructor, or destructor) since behaviour is undefined.     It is usually advisable that `operator=()` return a reference, not by value.

Comment: Each of these comments provide a wonderful insight into this problem and very useful tips on C++ programming techniques and paradigms as a whole. I really appreciate all of the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: Why is it that using a temporary variable and memcpy() does not
> work properly to copy the data from one object to another?

This is because of the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: "Your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do".

```
Tester A, B;

// ... at some point later.

A=B;
```

The instruction `A=B` instructs your computer to invoke `A`'s `operator=` overload. In the overload, `*this` becomes `A`.

```
tester operator=(const tester & data) const
{
  tester temp;    
  std::memcpy(&temp, &data, sizeof(tester));
  return temp;
}
```

Nothing here tells your computer that anything in `*this` gets modified. Since you did not tell your computer to modify `this->tester_value` it does not get modified.

Nothing here effectively sets `A.tester_value`. Instead, some new object gets created and returned. That's what you told your computer to do, so that's what it does, no more no less. But the return value is not used for anything. The return value here is the value for the entire `A=B;` statement ***itself***, which is not used for anything. It is the `operator=` ***itself*** that's responsible for assigning the new value of `this` object. It is not the return value from the `operator=` method that sets the new value of the object, it's the operator itself. In the `operator=` overload, what's on the right side of the `=` in the expression gets passed to `operator=` as a parameter, and what's on the left side of the `=` in the expression is `*this`.

> Question 2: What is the proper and most efficient way to do overload this
> operator?

That's already [answered by Stackoverflow's canonical on operating overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading). TLDR: it's "Example 2".

Comment: Addendum: The trailing `const` promises (enforced by the compiler) that the method will not modify (or allow to be modified) the instance on which the method is invoked. This is nonsensical for an assignment operator because the entire point of an assignment operator is to modify the instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! This makes a lot of sense.